# CSS: how to have child1 the same height as child2?

Tags: css, height

I have 2 elements and I want the height of 1st element to be equal to the height of 2nd element (this height can vary as this element can contain a picture or a video...).

I tried to encapsulate both of them in the same container, and to set `float:left` property to child 1 so that the height of the container is equal to child 2 (as floated elements do not add the height to the container).
The height of the container is ok (equal the height of child 2) but I still cannot have the height of child 1 equal to the height of its container.

You can see that is this fiddle (I would like to have the yellow part contained inside the green border, and a scroll bar appear in the yellow part... without using JavaScript):
 [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cskcd/)

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='child1'>
        test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1<br>test1
    </div>
    <div id='child2'>
        test2<br>test2<br>test2
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#container{
    border:green solid 5px;
}

#child1{
    float:left;
    background:yellow;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

#child2{
    background:blue;
}
```

Thank you for your help!
Pat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/cskcd/10/)**

[image]

```
#container{
    position:    relative;  /* needed */
    border:      green solid 5px;
}

#child1{
    position:    absolute;  /* needed */
    background:  yellow;
    overflow-y:  auto;
    height:      100%;      /* fit parent */
    width:       20%;       /* note */
}

#child2{
    margin-left: 20%;       /* note*/
    background:  blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the container value to be inherited by child 1? If so, child 1 should have a value of `height: inherit;`

Comment: Yes, but it does not work this way neither... as you can see in this modified example : http://jsfiddle.net/cskcd/4/

Comment: Assign a height to the container and make both child 1 and child 2 inherit height, then float both left.